# Not able to make a call to javascript function from hyperlink in each row of table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a dynamic table having each row as hyperlink and I am trying to call a js function passing row's text as string parameter.
But it shows(in console): {row's text} is not defined.

When I send no parameter, call to that function is made correctly, but when parameter is passed it shows error. I suspect it is expecting function which accept object as parameter, so I replaced each dot(.) with underscore(_), still it doesn't work.

Following is my code:

```
function showMessagePopup(data) {
$('#tbody').html("");
        for (var key in data) {
            keys.push(key);
            var keyStr=""+key;
            keyStr= keyStr.replace(/\./g, '__');
            // keyStr=keyStr.split('.').join("");
            // console.log("type of keyStr: "+keyStr+" "+typeof keyStr);
            var eachrow = '<tr>'
                + '<td><a href="javascript:showMessagePopup('+keyStr+')">' + key + '</a></td>'
                + '<td>' + data[key] + '</td>'
                + '</tr>';
            $('#tbody').append(eachrow);
        }  
}

function showMessagePopup(str) {

        console.log("in showMessagePopup");
        // some operation
}
```

I tried following :
keyStr= keyStr.replace(/./g, '__');
keyStr=keyStr.split('.').join("");

on printing type of keyStr:
console.log("type of "+typeof keyStr); and 
it prints string, but not sure why its not calling function.

Comment: As you are passing string wrap in quotes, `"javascript:showMessagePopup(\''+keyStr+'\')"`

Comment: no, I am not passing string wrap in quotes.

Comment: Try `"javascript:showMessagePopup(\''+keyStr+'\')"`

Answer (score 0):

Try onlick:

```
<a href="#" onlick="showMessagePopup('+keyStr+')">' + key + '</a>
```

Comment: Nothing happens on screen, just url has appended with #

Comment: Try without the javascript tag.

Comment: And you do know that you have two functions called showMessagePopup??

Comment: it is a typo, my first function name is populatetable().